# How to remove text from the body field in views and leave only <img> tag?

Tags: views

Good evening, i have articles that contain texts and images, i would like to know if there is any way in **views** to strip or remove the text from body field leaving just the **img** tag, i don´t want to use image field module.

Comment: If you use an Image field, it's very simple-- you just set the display to fields and then include only your Image field.  If for some reason you don't want to use that, you can code your own [Views field handler](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21FieldPluginBase.php/group/views_field_handlers/8.2.x).

Comment: Sounds more like a custom field formatter to me. Create a custom module with a custom field formatter for the textarea field and then do your regex or whatever to strip all content except the img tags and then apply that field formatter either to the body field in the view or to the field in the node types view mode.